# Pagers of two different contents are conflicting

Tags: views, nodes, paging, chaos-tool-suite

There are two contents in my website, say `CA` and `CB`, I created a view for each one and it displays 10 items and for the rest of the items pager is used. `CA` is in the `sidebar first` region and `CB` is the main content which lists some thing. the `Use AJAX:Yes` configuration is used for `CA` and `Use AJAX:No` for `CB` is used. the problem is when the `next` link in `CB` pager is clicked and the page goes to `www.example.com/content?pager=2` both `CA` and `CB` are going to the second page of the 10 contents. why they are conflicting and how do I can solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a different PagerID to the pager when editing the View.  This should compensate for the conflict.  By default, all pagers have an ID of 0, but if you need 2 views on the same page, then you need to manually select a different ID for one of them.

Comment: I can't believe I missed such simple thing. thanks